# Meteor - How can I limit which fields are published to the client?

Tags: meteor

I want to publish only a limited amount of data to the client.

I've tried to do it like this:

```coffee
# server
Meteor.publish('users', ->
  Meteor.users.find({},
    fields:
      services: 0
  )
)
```

But the client still receives the whole object.

```coffee
# client
Meteor.startup( ->
  Meteor.subscribe('users')
)

# ... 
# in another function
Meteor.users.find().observe( ->
  changed: (updated) ->
    console.log updated
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

```
Meteor.publish '', ->
    Posts.find({}, { fields: { title: 1, content: true, secret: false } });
```

what about add those {}

Comment: It's not possible to mix inclusion and exclusion of fields yet.

Answer (score 4):

The code below works for me (coffeescript). The `pwd` field isn't published.

#### Server

```cs
Meteor.publish "users", (userId) ->
  user = Users.find userId,
    fields:
      pwd: false

  return user
```

#### Client

```cs
Meteor.autosubscribe ->
    userId = Session.get SESSION_USER

    Meteor.subscribe 'users', userId
```

The only differences I see are

- `0` vs `false`... (should be a matter of taste, only)
- Your collection is accessed via `Meteor`
- In the client my subscription is placed inside a `autosubscribe` callback while you're using the `observe` method.

Do the fields exists in the result of `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` in the browsers console, too?

Comment: 1. 0 vs false, I don't it think makes a difference. The [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers) use 0. 2. Autosubscribe is useful when you want to limit which fields the client accesses, yes. But the fact remains that the client could access the other fields. And this is kind of a matter of security and revealing everything to the client is not good. 3. `Meteor.users` is the collection offered by the [auth](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Auth) branch of Meteor to handle user accounts. I wonder if this collection is different in this respect.

Comment: I will try `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't try the auth branch yet. Maybe this "special" collection is handled differently by Meteor.